# Incorrect Disqus Styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, disqus

I'm using the Disqus comments plugin on my wordpress site on http://swiftcarbon.com/carocap-the-journey-thus-far/

As you can see it is using a much darker blue (**rgb(0,0,238)**) than the sites blue (**##288ce4**), for the underlines, and anchor tags.

I've read the documentation on https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/545277 , but according to this article Disqus should apply a black colour to those links, which I'd be happy with.

So far I've tried to override the style with !important to change the colour which didn't work. I've even tried, although I know it's a no-no, to inject styles using the Javascript on the $(window).load() method to ensure the Disqus section is loaded before the js runs.

**css**

```
#disqus_thread .publisher-anchor-color {
  color: black !important;
}
```

**js**

```
$("#disqus_thread .publisher-anchor-color").css("color", "black !important");
```

or

```
$("#disqus_thread .publisher-anchor-color").removeClass("publisher-anchor-color);
```

Has anyone had a similar problem and managed to change the style.s

Answer (score 0):

The **final** working solution :

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #disqus_thread a {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        var embedVars = {
             "disqusConfig":{"platform":"wordpress@4.3.1","language":""},
            "disqusIdentifier":"5829 http:\/\/swiftcarbon.com\/?p=5829",
             "disqusShortname":"swiftcarbon","disqusTitle":"CAROCAP: THE JOURNEY THUS FAR",
             "disqusUrl":"http:\/\/swiftcarbon.com\/carocap-the-journey-thus-far\/",
             "options":{"manualSync":false},"postId":"5829"};
        /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://swiftcarbon.com/wp-content/plugins/disqus-comment-system/media/js/disqus.js?ver=4.3.1'></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="disqus_thread">
        <iframe id="dsq-app1" name="dsq-app1" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" tabindex="0" title="Disqus" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://disqus.com/embed/comments/?base=default&amp;version=9c6bf8c60a74cf4ced706cfda8a939f7&amp;f=swiftcarbon&amp;t_i=5829%20http%3A%2F%2Fswiftcarbon.com%2F%3Fp%3D5829&amp;t_u=http%3A%2F%2Fswiftcarbon.com%2Fcarocap-the-journey-thus-far%2F&amp;t_e=CAROCAP%3A%20THE%20JOURNEY%20THUS%20FAR&amp;t_d=CAROCAP%3A%20THE%20JOURNEY%20THUS%20FAR&amp;t_t=CAROCAP%3A%20THE%20JOURNEY%20THUS%20FAR&amp;s_o=default&amp;l=" style="width: 100% !important; border: 1px solid red !important; overflow: hidden !important; height: 475px !important;" horizontalscrolling="no" verticalscrolling="no"></iframe> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

**// UPDATED ** And the debug :

[image]

Comment: That won't work. The .publisher-anchor-color is the anchor.

Comment: @vard This is not a solution.

Comment: You're right, it's not necessary in the final code, but it can be usefull during the test phase to be sure that your scope is working.

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen have you tried my updated css ? In the *Link Color" paragraph, they explain that the inherited <a> color in #disqus_thread child nodes is the color used for disqus links

Comment: Updated my answer with a working example + screenshot

Comment: @aprovent The inherited colour I get is black but the class, I mentioned, from Disqus (.publisher-anchor-color) overrides this.

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen - It seems that you have a conflict in your css (not in Disqus css). I add the debug to my answer... has you can see, the Disqus .publisher-anchor-color a inherit of the correct color... Have you tried to search the blue color in your css ? or in other css dependencies ?

Comment: Works for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The disqus thread is get inside an iframe. You can't change the css of the frame content from the parent page. So this need to be resolved on disqus side - maybe there is an api option that you need to set.

Answer (score 0):

Disqus link colors are inherited from your site's "a" defined color, change your css to define new link colors, and it will automatically pick it up